# Howto return to virtual machine when remote desktop hangs?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop

I'm using a **vmware** virtual machine running **ubuntu linux** and from there I connect to a Windows XP machine using **rdesktop** through a VPN tunnel. This configuration is given and cannot be changed.

From time to time my internet connection does a reconnect. Then the running rdesktop (running in **fullscreen mode**) process **freezes** and isn't usable anymore. Now I want to return to the underlying linux and **restart** the rdesktop process. But I'm not able to **get out of fullscreen rdesktop mode** and so I cannot access the ubuntu desktop to kill any process.

My solution is to **reboot** the vmware and start the rdesktop again.

Is there a better way to get the configuration running again after a freeze?

EDIT:

I have **no admin rights** for the linux system. Everything must be done with user rights.

Answer (score 2):

Turn on the X escape hatch:

```
$ gnome-keyboard-properties
```

and then Layouts ➤ Options... ➤ Key sequence to kill the X server ➤ enable.

[Unable to debug/reproduce Ubuntu crash](https://superuser.com/questions/160620/unable-to-debug-reproduce-ubuntu-crash/160631#160631)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> doesn't work?

How about switching to a different virtual console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, logging in, and killing your rdesktop process?

Or, ssh to your Ubuntu machine from your host OS and killing it that way?

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Enter switches the vm from fullscreen to window mode, but I can't get a terminal, because rdesktop fills all the screen.

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-F1 doesn't work, don't know why. Even when no rdesktop is startet.

Comment: sshd isn't enabled, so I can't connect this way.

Comment: Can you not resize the un-fullscreen'd rdesktop window?

Comment: rdesktop is frozen and doesn't react to any action.

Comment: Your window manager should still let you resize or minimize it.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 has been disabled in recent Ubuntu releases (sigh...) Try Alt+F4 to close rdesktop, perhaps? Or Ctrl+Esc to get a window manager action menu?

Comment: Try Ctrl+Alt, then Ctrl+Esc. If not, having two monitors is a solution with other benefits, the second one will get you access to your desktop (though you still have to Ctrl-Alt to let the mouse escape the full screen)